# No se ejecuta MySQL (XAMPP - MacOS) aún con el servidor arrancado

Tags: mysql, xampp, macos

Tengo `XAMPP` instalado en `MacOS`. No he instalado `MySQL` a parte, sólo `XAMPP`.
Los servidores y `MySQL` arrancan sin problema y puedo gestionar las bases de datos desde `PHPMyAdmin` o `Sequel Pro`, pero al intentar acceder a ellas a través de algún documento `.html` o `.php` (alta de datos o consulta a través de formularios), `MySQL` no se ejecuta y me da `error 500` en el navegador.

Traté de añadir a mi `/~` un archivo `.bash_profile` con el siguiente contenido:

```
source ~/.profile
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
```

Con eso no conseguí añadir `mysql` al `PATH` y tampoco sé si eso solucionaría mi error.

Edito:
Sigo sin conseguir que ningún script `php` me conecte a la base de datos.
Voy a explayarme un poco más porque creo que no me expliqué correctamente:

Instalé `XAMPP 8.0.12` para poder trabajar en `localhost` con scripts `php` y documentos `HTML`. Puedo arrancar los tres servidores sin problema alguno (`Apache`, `MySQL` y el `FTP`).
Tengo un fichero de conexión en `php` "utilDB.php":

```
<?php
function conectarMySQL(
    $schema = 'test',
    $usu = 'root',
    $pwd = '',
    $host = 'localhost'
    ) {
        try {
            $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$schema";
            $db = new PDO($dsn, $usu, $pwd);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            print ("ERROR de conexión a $schema");
            die();
        }
        return $db;
}
?>
```

(También he probado con `'127.0.0.1'`para el `host` en lugar de `'localhost'`, con el mismo resultado)
Desde otro fichero "ej01.php", muy sencillo para empezar a hacer pruebas de conexión, tengo esto actualmente:

```
<?php
require_once '../../utilDB.php';
$bd = conectarMySQL();
$sql = <<<SQL
insert into persona(id,nombre)
values(3,'ana')
SQL;

try {
    $bd->exec($sql);
    echo 'Persona creada';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'ID duplicado';
}

$filas = $bd->query($sql);

foreach ($filas as $fila) {
    echo "ID:" . $fila['id'] . ", Nombre: " . $fila['nombre'] . "<br/>\n";
}
?>
```

Por supuesto, he hecho la prueba dejando "utilDB.php" en el mismo directorio para evitar problemas de rutas relativas, pero sigue sin funcionar.
Pensando que pudiese tener que ver, seguí intentando añadir `mysql` al `PATH` y ya puedo ejecutarlo sin problemas en la consola, pero eso no soluciona mis problemas.
Después de varios intentos, cambiando algunas cosas en el código, me ha ejecutado el script en `Chrome` y me ha dado el "error" del `catch`. Este es el contenido de `$e`:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.persona' doesn't exist in /Users/chapa/eclipse/workspacePHP/daw2/t5_BBDD/ejemplos/ejemplo01/ej01.php:11 Stack trace: #0 /Users/chapa/eclipse/workspacePHP/daw2/t5_BBDD/ejemplos/ejemplo01/ej01.php(11): PDO->exec('insert into per...') #1 {main}
```

Y éste es el problema. Los scripts de `php` no me conectan con `MySQL`.

Comment: Prueba a reinstalar xampp. Otro error común es que al intentarte conectar con la base de datos desde PhP no pongas bien el user/la contraseña y por eso no funcione. Si no funciona todo lo anterior, por favor, especifica un poco mas tu problema para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Anteriormente utilizaba MAMP y tenía el mismo problema: el servidor del localhost me arrancaba y yo podía gestionar la bbdd. Pero a la hora de hacer alguna consulta o similar desde un formulario con php, no me accede a la base de datos. Ya probé que el usuario y la contraseña estuviesen correctos (está todo por defecto) y probé a cambiar los puertos en MAMP para MySQL.
Al no solucionar nada desinstalé e instalé XAMPP. Todo igual.
No sé si tendré que instalar MySQL a parte, añadir mysql al path o algo así. 
No se explicar mejor el problema.

Comment: Para puntualizar: Estoy en clase y mis ejercicios están idénticos a los del profesor, por lo que se descartan problemas de código. El problema es con MySQL (él no maneja macos). Supongo que será algo como descomentar en windows la línea `extension=pdo_mysql` de php.ini, pero no sé si tengo que hacer algo similar en mac habiendo instalado sólo XAMPP